# System cannot find org.apache.maven.wrapper.MavenWrapperMain which exists

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, build

When attempting to use `maven's clean` or `install` function on a **SpringBoot Java** program, I ran into the following error (Full error at the bottom). The main issue appears to be what I have highlighted below.

```
The system cannot find the file D:\01. GitHub\springBootTutorial\.mvn\wrapper\maven-wrapper.properties.
```

Currently, I have verified that the file exists and these are the contents (unchanged from creation). The error pops up when I attempt to do other actions like `install`, `test`.

**maven-wrapper.properties**

```
distributionUrl=https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/apache-maven/3.8.6/apache-maven-3.8.6-bin.zip
wrapperUrl=https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/wrapper/maven-wrapper/3.1.0/maven-wrapper-3.1.0.jar
```

I believe this is something to do with filepath, currently when I execute the `clean` command by clicking on the button inside `VSCode`, I am in `D:\01. GitHub\springBootTutorial>` which seems to work when running the `Java` program. I have ensured that `Maven` is indeed installed with `mvn -v` which returns the version I have.

Do let me know how I can begin troubleshooting this!

**Full error**

```
D:\01. GitHub\springBootTutorial>"d:\01. GitHub\springBootTutorial\demo\mvnw.cmd" install -f "d:\01. GitHub\springBootTutorial\demo\pom.xml" 
The system cannot find the file D:\01. GitHub\springBootTutorial\.mvn\wrapper\maven-wrapper.properties.
Exception calling "DownloadFile" with "2" argument(s): "An exception occurred during a WebClient request."
At line:1 char:282
+ ... pe]::Tls12; $webclient.DownloadFile('https://repo.maven.apache.org/ma ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebException
 
Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.maven.wrapper.MavenWrapperMain
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.maven.wrapper.MavenWrapperMain
```

Comment: Do you have the same problem with a freshly downloaded and unzipped maven?

Comment: I have redownloaded and changed `maven` and the problem still persists. I am a bit unsure how I got `maven` inside the `Spring` application because I used the initializer. Currently looking into how to install `maven` inside an existing `Spring` application.

Comment: The spring initializr put the wrapper inside your project and is correctly configured ... can you show a link on your project or make that project on Github or alike?

Comment: This is my project on (**Github**) [https://github.com/peek00/java-spring-boot]! Do help me take a look if there are any issues. Really appreciate it.